# how to configure linux vm as router which communicate between two subnets

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, ubuntu-12.04, vmware-player

I have 3 virtual machines installed on vmplayer. Out of which I have made two of them as host of two different network. `Host1 ip=192.168.1.13 gateway=192.168.1.11` and `Host2 ip=192.168.2.14` and `gateway=192.168.2.12` . Now I want the third virtual machine as router which can transfer packets from first virtual machine to second virtual machine has two adapters `eth0 ip=192.168.1.11` and `eth1 ip=192.168.2.12` . Host1 is connected to `eth0` and Host2 is connected to `eth1`. How shall I configure the router so that the two hosts can communicate and `NAT`'ing could be performed? Please do reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what OS so you have to deal with assumptions - so assuming Debian derivative

Enable forwarding. In /etc/sysctl.conf set:
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

That is all you need to get to ping A -> B.

Because you also want NAT for some reason, in /etc/rc.local - add modules you need - eg:

```
modprobe ipt_conntrack
modprobe ip_conntrack
modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
modprobe ip_nat_ftp
modprobe ip_conntrack_irc
modprobe ip_nat_irc
modprobe ip_nat_snmp_basic
```

Also in /etc/rc.local add:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.11
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.2.12
```

If you wanted the gateway to also access the internet for example, then you would give it a third interface, eg, eth2 with an IP address on your LAN, eg 10.0.0.200 then add this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.200
```

or if it had a DHCP address (ie, its not a static address) then do this instead

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
```

then lastly make sure that the gateway has a default route pointing to your Internet LAN gateway, fiber line or DSL modem. This would be done automatically anyway if it's DHCP assigned.

Comment: Sorry, but the ping is still not working.Do I have to keep the router configured virtual machine adaptors set as NAT?

Comment: You do need to restart networking after enabling ip_forward. Did you do that?

Comment: I just made 3 VM's and tested the above. Works perfectly in both cases - ie, without NAT and with NAT (Heading out for a long weekend's leave so I'll check back Tuesday see how you got on).

Comment: Thank you. It worked fine. Now, I am getting problem with making same router machine as bridge and perform bridging. Can you help? :)

Comment: Make a new question with details Krati and I'll try to have a look. Also mark this as the answer so the other Googlers see it easier :-)